# Magento 1.5.1: new customer dashboard block

Tags: url, magento, mapping, block

I am going mental trying to create a new very simple section on my customer dashboard. Something like www.mymagentosite.com/customer/rid (rid includes only static links). However, when I try to access www.mymagentosite.com/customer/rid, I always get a 404 Magento page (no exceptions or system message in the log files)

What am I missing?

Thank you

What I have done so far is:

-create a new Block under /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Dashboard/Rid.php

```
class Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard_Rid extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{ 
  public function getCustomer()
  {
      return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
  } 

}
```

-create a new controller under /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/RidController.php

```
class Mage_Customer_RidController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
  protected function _getSession()
  {
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
  }

  public function preDispatch()
  {
    parent::preDispatch();

    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
        $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
    }
  }

  public function indexAction()
  {
    if (count($this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getAddresses())) {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('rid');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setRefererUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/new'));
    }
  }
}
```

-create a new helper under /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Helper/Rid.php

```
class Mage_Customer_Helper_Rid extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

  public function getRenderer($renderer)
  {
    if(is_string($renderer) && $className = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($renderer)) {
        return new $className();
    } else {
        return $renderer;
    }
  }

}
```

-edit the file /app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/layout/customer.xml

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- EXISTING CODE -->
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
    <!-- EXISTING CODE -->
   <block type="customer/account_dashboard_rid" name="rid" as="rid" 
              template="customer/account/dashboard/rid.phtml"></block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>

<customer_rid_index translate="label">
    <label>RID</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/rid" name="address_book" 
               template="customer/account/dashboard/rid.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_rid_index>
```

-create /app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/template/customer/account/dashboard/rid.phtml

Comment: please paste your config.xml, which is the real interesting one for your problem

Comment: Hi @osdave, I didn't touch the config.xml. It's the standard config.xml you can find in the basic installation. Which part should I change? Thank you for your help!

Comment: oups, sorry, didn't see you didn't create a module, but hacking the core (which you really shouldn't do). I've copied your code and it's working fine here. cache maybe?

Comment: @OSdave, I created all the new code in "local" so I didn't really hacked the core. Just took the short way (or that's what I though). So, are you saying that you edited/created only the files I listed and if you type /customer/rid, it shows the actual page? Did you touch other XMLs? Cache (unfortunately) seems not to be part of the problem/solution on my side. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Magento to use your controller and not the core:

"An important key to note here is that with controllers, Magento does not autoload them like it does with blocks and models."

http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                         <My_Module before="Mage_Checkout">My_Module_Checkout</My_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```